# What keyboard shortcut(s) can I use to close the error output panel on VSCode when it pops up?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hit Save, there is some error, a panel pops up with the tab "OUTPUT" open. How do I close it without using the mouse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Toggle Panel" command `workbench.action.togglePanel`

Default keybinding: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

Mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>